# Can I call me Anti-Anti-SpamBot or how?

Tags: technical, nicknames

Will it be comprehensible to take a nickname calling me Anti-Anti-SpamBot
to convey the idea that communication on internet (like commenting in blogs, registration and posting in forums, etc.) [became practically impossible without tools facilitating posting, like spam bots](http://goo.gl/SrqaX)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anti-anti Spambot seems to insinuate a fondness for Spambots.

How about instead: "The Anti-Spambot Aficionado". But in Spanish, that will increase the girth of its awesomeness.

EDIT: Terribly sorry, late night spelling let me down.

Comment: +1 Thanks any internationally understood slang is welcome!

Comment: @vgv8: “The Anti-Spambot Oficiando” is indeed awesome, but I’m not so sure about its being internationally understood.  I’d never come across *oficiando* before, and googling for it, I can’t find many examples of it being used in an English-speaking context.

Comment: Fixed the spelling there, although "The Anti-Spambot Oficiando" could be amusing.

Comment: I love this one, but I would think it would have to be "spambot-aficionado'.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with Miel. I don't think *Anti-anti-spambot* means that you are *pro-spambot* per se, only that you are against measures taken to defeat spambots. This may be a small distinction, and you may well be a [fifth-columnist](http://www.answers.com/topic/fifth-column), or someone who wants to buy [peace for our time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville_Chamberlain), or are just [kinky that way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masochist).

I'll offer a parallel: People who are against childhood vaccinations are not necessarily *for* the disease in question.

Comment: +1, strongly agreed!  Two antis don’t necessarily make a pro.  Anti-anti-spambot seems excellent to me, and I’d imagine most people would understand it, especially given some context.

Comment: You're right of course, I realized that when I wrote my answer, but the difference between ant-anti and pro is rather subtle, and since it's a nickname, and not embedded in an explanatory text, I'm not sure that difference will come across.

The parallel you give is really bad: anti-vaccination is not a combination of two anti's (and no, you can't replace vaccination with anti-disease).

Answer (score 1):

Anti-anti-spambot would convey the idea that you are pro-spambot, not why that is your opinion.

Comment: +1 thanks, and what nickname, in your opinion, would convey the idea?

Comment: I like Tom Ravencrofts suggestion, but see my comment there.